# Node "No such file or directory" with certain packages

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I installed two packages via `npm`:

- `alsatian@1.0.0-alpha.7`
- `gulp@3.9.1`

As I am using `nvm` to manage my `node` versions, the CLI files for the two packages were installed at the following paths:

- `/home/james/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/lib/alsatian/cli/alsatian-cli.js`
- `/home/james/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/lib/gulp/bin/gulp.js`

---

When I run the command `gulp`, the command runs correctly. However when I run the command `alsatian` I get the following output:

```
: No such file or directory
```

---

I replaced both CLI files with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

console.log("If you see this, it worked!");
```

When I typed the command `gulp`, I get the message `If you see this, it worked!`. However, when I type the command `alsatian` I get the same `No such file or directory` message as before.

---

Using the `which` command I am certain that the files I have modified are the correct files for the packages, and by using the `stat` command I can see that I have the same permissions for the package files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the CLI file for `alsatian` containing carriage return characters. Enforcing `LF` line endings solved the issue.